# Converting Java -> Grails ... How do I load these properties?

Tags: grails

I'm converting a Java web app to Grails (1.2.1).  In my Java app, I have a singleton that loads properties from a ".properties" file.  I've seen I can put that loading into the "Config.groovy" conf file.  If my properties are loaded in Config.groovy, how do I load them in my Java file?  Here is how I'm doing it when the Config was loaded in java ...

Long interval = ConfigSingleton.getInstance().getGlobalCacheRefreshInterval();

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Do you wish to move .properties file contents to `Config.groovy`, or to load `.properties` file during application startup?

Answer (score 3):

Adapted from the [Grails User Guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.1%20Basic%20Configuration):

You can add your own configuration in `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`, for example:

```
globalCacheRefreshInterval = 120
```

Then later in your application you can access these settings in one of two ways. The most common is via the `GrailsApplication` object, which is available as a variable in controllers and tag libraries:

```
Long interval = grailsApplication.config.globalCacheRefreshInterval
```

The other way involves getting a reference to the `ConfigurationHolder` class that holds a reference to the configuration object:

```
def config = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder.config
Long interval = config.globalCacheRefreshInterval
```

If you want to acess this configuration from a **Java** class, you can use:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder;
...
Map config = ConfigurationHolder.getFlatConfig();
Long interval = (Long) config.get("globalCacheRefreshInterval");
```

Attention for the correct type in your `Config.groovy`. In the case above, your configuration property must be defined as a Long:

```
globalCacheRefreshInterval = 120L
```

Comment: Hi, I would like to add the configuration to the Config.groovy file, so that part of the question is answered, but how do I then access the file from a .java file?  IN other words, how do I write, "def config = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder.config
Long interval = config.globalCacheRefreshInterval" in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You should also checkout the [ConfigSlurper class](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper) (this is what grails uses to load its config file).

Answer (score 0):

Dave if what you need is to load the properties file as it is without having to move them to the Config.groovy manually, you can the following inside the Config.groovy file:

```
 grails.config.locations = [
          "file:" + "/pathWhereFileLives/fileName.properties"
  ]
```

This will load all the properties you have in the file in the Grails configuration class. Something to be aware of is that if you have a property in the Config.groovy and the properties file with the same name, the one from the properties file will override the value of the one from Config.groovy

You can find more information about the Grails external configurations [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.4%20Externalized%20Configuration).